# Display message during release mode for C# metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` for metro app during release mode won't not print anything in Visual Studio's windows.

May I know, how I can display message in Visual Studio's windows, during release mode for C# metro app?

Answer (score 1):

you can always use `Trace.WriteLine()`, it works in both `Debug` and `Release` mode.

Comment: But I cannot find `Trace.WriteLine` in Metro.